# updated url not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, url

i try this code for call current page with new updated query string :

```
onclick="ijk=(confirm(\'Are u sure\')?\''.$dgdBack.'\'+xallInput():\''.$dgdBack.'\');
alert(ijk);
window.location.href=ijk;"
```

assume that `$dgdBack` has the value : `"test1.php?a=1&b=qaz"`

function xallinput returns all input=value pair of current form on my page and

`alert(ijk)` shows every thing ok : `"test1.php?a=1&b=qaz&i1=v1&i2=v2"`

but when new page loading, url has only first part `(test1.php?a=1&b=qaz)`

why?

Comment: can you provide the code for where it actually tries to bring up the new page?

Comment: can you format your question, i can't make any sense of what you are trying to do...

Comment: simple it : test1.php?a=1&b=qaz is current page. when i click on the update botton (i drive it with onclick event), lunch confirm function to get my confirm. then xallInput function fire & return all input & values on my form as string. i add it to the end of $dgdBack variable that contain "test1.php?a=1&b=qaz" & save it as ijk variable. the result of ijk "test1.php?a=1&b=qaz&i1=v1&i2=v2" & alert(ijk) shows this. when window.location.href=ijk is fire, at the top of test1.php i print the current url by basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) function & only "test1.php?a=1&b=qaz" is display. why?

Answer (score 0):

In which element consist "onclick" ?. Have you checked any "header('Location: ')" in test1.php?.

Anyway try following code. "return false" stop all further operation in javascript. And it is equivalent to "event.preventDefault()"

```
onclick="ijk=(confirm(\'Are u sure\')?\''.$dgdBack.'\'+xallInput():\''.$dgdBack.'\');
alert(ijk);
window.location.href=ijk; return false;"
```

Comment: return false has no effect. i think the encoding url or any setting on php.ini or httpd.conf cause this problem. if i add extra char such as * or ^ to url param ($dgdBack variable) every thing ok for 1 or 2 times loading page and for the next load the url goes wrong again.

Comment: @A.Pourhadi Really weird behaviour. Can you post your PHP code?